# select opposite operation group by month SQL Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Iam trying to extract a list of operation that was inactive in each month :

table 1 "all_opreration" is containing the whole list of operation id
[table all_operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Nfb.png)

the second table "active_operation" is containing the operations that was active on the specified month

[table active operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0jw1.png)

So I want to get "inactive operation" by month (for each month the operation that was not in active_operation table

==> Wished table :

[wished table inactive operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToXi0.png)

I have tried several ways but without success

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to left join and check the the right side is NULL.  You will need to expand your all_operations to have all dates but this can be done with a cross join.  Like this:

Set up:

```
create table all_ops (op_id varchar(32));
insert into all_ops values ('A'), ('B'), ('C');

create table active_ops (month date, op_id varchar(32));
insert into active_ops values ('2021-10-01', 'A'),
('2021-10-01', 'B'),
('2021-07-01', 'C');
```

Find the missing data / id pairs:

```
select l.month, l.op_id 
from (
  select month, op_id
  from all_ops 
  cross join (select distinct month from active_ops) m
  ) l
left join active_ops r
on l.op_id = r.op_id and l.month = r.month
where r.op_id is null;
```